# How can a file be compressed to less than its entropy?

Tags: r, compression, entropy

I created a file that contains 100,000 numbers that were drawn uniformly (with probability 1/8) from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.

When a look at the size of this file on my hard-disk it is 293 KB (kilo-byte) which makes sense because one needs 3 bits to "identify" a number between 1 and 8 and 3*100,000 = 300 KB.

Next I compress the file using Win-zip and find that the file is reduced to only 57 KB ! How can this be since I expect that the random-number generator I used for my draws is - for all practical purposes -  ideal. This means that the sequence should be truly random and the size of the file should therefore be given by its entropy ( which is 300 KB)?

Comment: I used the R-language:   y  <- sample(1:8,size=100000,replace=T)

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you are confused about certain concepts.

3 bits times 100,000 gives you 300,000 ***bits***, and there are 8 bits to the byte, which corresponds to roughly 37.5 KB.  That's a far cry from 300 KB.

(And in any case, if you were to create "a file that contains 100,000 numbers", there is no magic fairy sitting on your hard disk, who will figure out the min & max range of your numbers, and store them in the file using the smallest number of bits necessary to represent them all.)

So, it is very important to get it out of the way that 300 KB has absolutely nothing to do with the entropy of 100,000 single-digit numbers.

You told us absolutely nothing about how you created that file, so its file format is a mystery, but we can make some simple calculations and guesses: 293 KB times 1024 is 300,000, so what you have is a 300,000 byte file.  Which means that you are writing 3 bytes per number.  Which means that ***you have written these numbers as text***, in a text file, either each digit followed by a comma, then followed by a space, or each digit followed by a carriage return and a linefeed, or something similar.

Text file formats are extremely wasteful in terms of storage space.

So, yes, this is a highly compressible file consisting mostly of identical bytes, and even the bytes that are not identical (the digits) all map to just 3 bits each, so it is no wonder that the entire file gets compressed so well.

No laws of nature were harmed during the making of this question.

Comment: thank you for clearing my confusions ! Interestingly when I run different

Comment: thank you ! You are perfectly right: dividing the size by 8 gets already quite close to the observed size! Interestingly when I run the exercise applying different compression algorithms directly (from within R without explicitly saving the file down) I find 0.38 bytes per digit for the best compressors which is pretty close to the theoretical value of 3/8=0.375. (:-